# Custom sorting rule for one column in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have simple web app with GridView to represent the data and between asp:GridView tags I have AllowSorting="True" which works fine except of one column which is string and I'm keeping there date in Week_Day column (e.g. 9/11/2017).

Is there any way how to create custom sorting rule (cast to date and sort in ascending order) just for this particular column?

I'll appreciate any of your help.

Comment: are you sorting from database or in C#?

Comment: pulling the data from db

Comment: Sorting is handled on C# code or in database side Like Order by is written in SQl or in C# DataTable?

Comment: Yeah, that's great idea... let me try that. I'm just pulling data with select * so I'm gonna try cast column there.

Comment: If you have varchar data type then ORDER BY 
   CONVERT(DateTime, EventDate,101)  ASC or if all other columns are varchar and using rownumber case orderby then   WHEN @SortColumn = 'ReferralDate'
          THEN replace(convert(VARCHAR(8), RM.CreatedDateTime, 112) + convert(VARCHAR(8), RM.CreatedDateTime, 114), ':', '')